# numix theme not working on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

So, what i did was

```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:numix/ppa
> sudo apt-get update 
> sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

Then i went to unity-tweak-tool and selected numix-something under theme-icons tab.

And, nothing happened. Icons in my menu did not change at all. Tried launching unity-tweak-tool as root, no good.

Ideas?

Comment: Just noticed that numix theme DID apply for icons in Ubuntu's native Settings app. Totally weird.

Comment: this belongs on [su] or ask ubuntu.